# batman.js data-route adding characters to url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, batman.js

I have a html template doing this.

```
<ul id="things">
  <li data-foreach-thing="Thing.all" data-mixin="animation">
    <a data-route="routes.things[thing].new" data-bind="thing.id"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `data-route` attribute is returning a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#!/things/new
```

I don't know why it is adding the `#!`

I'm using batman.js 0.9 with rails 3.1

Any help figuring this out is be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know why batman does this, but #! is called a hashbang and is really useful for SEO.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, but also when I click on my link, it will fill in the URL, but doesn't update my view. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your javaqscript console? Past them here if so, I took a shot at what your problem might be below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good description of hash bang urls [hash bang urls](http://www.quora.com/Are-hashbang-URLs-a-recommended-practice). This is normal for batman to do this (pretty much all javascript frameworks do this). You can enable "pushstate:true" which will disable it (however it will fall back to hash bang if you're on a legacy browser).

Regarding your batman.js view not being rendered, I ran into a similar issue. I didn't have an error in my chrome console, however the view wasn't being rendered. You need to make sure you have a data-yield attribute for your view to attach to.

For example:

```
<div id="container" data-yield="main">
</div>
```

Excerpt from [batman.js github](https://github.com/Shopify/batman):

> Now when you navigate to /#!/faq/what-is-art, the dispatcher runs this
>   faq action with {questionID: "what-is-art"}. It also makes an implicit
>   call to @render, which by default will look for a view at
>   /views/app/faq.html. The view is rendered within the main content
>   container of the page, which is designated by setting
>   data-yield="main" on some tag in the layout's HTML. You can prevent
>   this implicit rendering by calling @render false in your action.

Are you trying to show a link to the show action for the thing? It should look like this if you are:

```
<ul id="things">
  <li data-foreach-thing="Thing.all" data-mixin="animation">
    <a data-route="routes.things[thing]" data-bind="thing.id"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's an example of some code I'm using (the order of the data- attributes doesn't matter):

```
  <div data-foreach-section="sections" data-mixin="animation">
    <a data-bind="section.SectionId" data-route="routes.sections[section]"></a>
    <p data-bind="section.Name"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't get it to work. When I expect the code I just see href="#" no model or id at all...

Comment: @AlfredNerstu We're iterating through sections (which will need to be populated by the controller). Check to see if sections has anything inside of it. If it doesn't, that's probably why you're getting a blank href.

Comment: I get the rest of the data like the title and body in my case but not the link url...